# Pandas Groupby - Append lists

Tags: python, pandas

My pandas DataFrame has a column with `lists dtype`. I'd like to `Group By` and aggregate the DataFrame and append the lists.

Here's a sample DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'id': [1, 1, 2],
                   'cat': ['A','A','B'],
                   'lst': [['l0','l1','l2'],['l3','l4'],['lb']],
                   'v': [10, 20, 10]
                 })
```

Use `mean` to aggregate column `v`.

Expected output:

```
id  cat lst                         v

1   A   ['l0','l1','l2','l3','l4']  15
2   B   ['lb']                      10
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple way would be to aggregate the `lst` column using `sum` and `v` using `mean`:

```
df.groupby(['id', 'cat'], as_index=False).agg({'lst': 'sum', 'v': 'mean'})
```

---

```
   id cat                   lst     v
0   1   A  [l0, l1, l2, l3, l4]  15.0
1   2   B                  [lb]  10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

This works

```
# groupby and call lambda that flattens a nested list on lst and mean on v
df.groupby(['id', 'cat'], as_index=False).agg({'lst': lambda lst: [x for s_l in lst for x in s_l], 'v':'mean'})
   id cat                   lst     v
0   1   A  [l0, l1, l2, l3, l4]  15.0
1   2   B                  [lb]  10.0
```